# FOSUserBundle extend RegisterForm

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Im using Symfony 2.8.x and FOSUserBundle.

I try to expand my User with a few fields like last name and first name... I do it like the document says
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

When i try to register following Message comes

```
Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "getName()", "name()", "isName()", "hasName()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\User"
```

This is my Registration Class

```
    <?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

and this is my User Class

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     *
     */
    protected $name;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     *
     */

    protected $firstname;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $mentorid;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with that Problem?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to do what Andrey suggests. You need to generate the setters and getters for your fields. You can do it manually, but I would say it's safer to start with automatically generate methods which afterwards you can customise as needed. You need to run

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/User
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#generating-getters-and-setters for more details

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add setter and getter for field 'name'?
Using for example doctrine:generate:entities YourBundleName

Comment: i tried to add a setter into User.php and in RegistrationType.php . Both didnt worked or created a new error.

Comment: This is a typical error, which means that you don't have getter for this field in entity class.
So, add public getter in "AppBundle\Entity\User" and if your code wouldn't work, post full entity class code here.

Comment: i restarted the server and now it looks like it works, but i cant register anymore.